# Put Self-Service Login Page in an iframe to avoid repetition when loggin in / I frame not loading

Tags: customer-portal, css, html, visualforce, iframe

I need help with my Self-Service Login Page as is working OK when you load the page. However, when you log in you get a white screen can you help me please with this problem ASAP.[image]

http://rma.airacom.com/

Please not this image is after you login not when you load the page the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its a problem with your Browser!
I tried it out and it worked fine.
With Firefox 40.0.3

Are you aware of the limitations inside an iframe?

Do you have more informations about your problem?

[image: It works]

Comment: The logging screen is working ok, but when you logging is not working is a blank screen about the "Are you aware of the limitations inside an iframe?" not 100% percent sure on saleforce unless there is another option available.

Comment: Any ideas please i need help